# javascript/typescript - add item to object only if defined

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, object

assume i have an object call userData = {..}

and I want to define an object userDataB with properties a,b,c and d from userData but only of those which defined. I know I can do something like this:

```
userDataB = {}
if(userData.a){userDataB.a = a};
if(userData.b){userDataB.b = b};
...
```

but, there is something cleaner? mayber from es5 or es6?

Comment: Note that your code will produce `{}` for `{ a: 0, b: "" }`, not sure if that is intended.

Answer (score 2):

This might help too

```
const object1 = {
    a: 'somestring',
    b: 42,
    c: false,
    d: undefined
};
let object2 = Object.assign(
    ...Object.entries(object1).map(obj =>
        obj[1] !== undefined ? { [obj[0]]: obj[1] } : {}
    )
);
```

or this

```
let object2 = Object.assign(
    ...Object.keys(object1).map(key =>
        object1[key] !== undefined ? { [key]: object1[key] } : {}
    )
);
```

or this

```
let object2 = Object.entries(object1).reduce(
    (a, v) => (v[1] !== undefined ? Object.assign(a, { [v[0]]: v[1] }) : a),
    {}
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `JSON` methods - they auto-strip `undefined` properties:

```js
var userData = {
  a: "a",
  b: false,
  c: undefined,
  d: 0
};

var userDataB = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(userData));

console.log(userDataB);
```

Comment: This will a) also remove any method, Map, Set, Symbolic key etc. b) fail for circular references

Answer (score 0):

Just use `Object.assign()` to clone it into a new object:

```js
var userData = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  d: 3
}
userDataB = Object.assign({}, userData);
console.log(userDataB);
```

For `undefined` or `null` values:

```js
var userData = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: null,
  d: 3,
  e: undefined
}
var userDataB = Object.assign({}, userData);
Object.keys(userDataB).forEach((key) => (userDataB[key] == null) && delete userDataB[key])
console.log(userDataB);
```

Comment: This doesn't deal with the "is defined" part of the problem.

Comment: @JackBashford now it does

Comment: I look for cleaner sultion

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your use case, this might work for you:

```
const newObj = Object.keys(oldObj).reduce((all,propertyName) => {
  if(oldObj[propertyName] != null){ // change this to your criteria
    all[propertyName] = oldObj[propertyName];
  }
  return all;
},{});
```